# Display two columns but one of them is in union with another column from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to display **two columns** from the first table with an **UNION** with another table, but I only want **one column** from this second table to be in union with the first.

I wrote this SQL code:

```
SELECT type, nuavion 
FROM avion 
UNION 
SELECT codetype 
FROM appareil
```

but I get an "incorrect syntax" error - of course, because the number of columns isn't the same, but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select the same number of columns/fields. The easiest way is to select a NULL e.g.,

```
SELECT type,nuavion 
FROM avion 
  UNION 
SELECT codetype, NULL
FROM appareil
```

Of course, if you want another value in the second column (like `''`, `'n/a'`, etc) feel free to use that rather than NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT type
     , nuavion 
FROM avion 
UNION 
SELECT codetype AS type
      , NULL AS nuavion 
 FROM appareil
```